# GRUB menu doesn't show Windows 7 option

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I'm in need of help to repair my Dual OS (Windows & Ubuntu), I installed Ubuntu after installing Windows 7 but GRUB menu doesn't show Windows 7 option to select.

I'm here to ask how can I make my computer a dual OS boot such that Windows 7 is already installed.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 40.0 GB, 40020664320 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4865 cylinders, total 78165360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk identifier: 0x000abaf4

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1   *        2048    74010623    37004288   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        74012670    78163967     2075649    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        74012672    78163967     2075648   82  Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes

255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors

Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk identifier: 0xf449f449


Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sdb1   *          63   251658224   125829081    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       251658225   503316449   125829112+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb3       503316450   754974674   125829112+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       754974675   976768064   110896695    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb5       251658288   503316449   125829081    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Answer (score 1):

Strongly recommend this utility

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Used it several times to recover my "Windows"

You can use the Live-CD to install it and then use it to recover your Windows partition back into the grub boot menu.

As part of the process of running this utility it generates a report and stores it here http://paste.ubuntu.com/5592460/ so you can refer to it later. The link is an example of someone else who had their grub repaired.

Comment: Would you kindly explain how you used the Live CD to recover the Windows partition? I've tried Boot Repair but it doesn't restore the item entry in Grub.

In case it helps, here's my paste. http://paste2.org/O8a3BDe9